# SharePoint Online sharing, NoScript Isnt enabled on the hostsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I've created some functions that is really about sharing objects with external users via the JSOM api in SharePoint.

```
var result = SP.Web.shareObject(ctx, urlToDocument,
                                        peoplePickerInput, roleValue, groupId, propageAcl,
                                        sendEmail, includedAnonymousLinkInEmail, emailSubject,
                                        emailBody, useSimplifiedRoles);
```

The code is working fine while in a scripteditor on a page in the same site as the library I'm sharing objects from. Then I get statuscode 0 and the user gets an email invitation.

But when I try the same code from a page in another site or even a SharePoint Hosted App i get: statuscode -3 and errormessage:

```
"MountPoint security error: NoScript isn't enabled on the host site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of creating the "ctx" (ClientContext) from the same location where the object is being shared.
So the clientcontext needed to be dynamically created with the object parent url.
ex:

Object url: "/sites/intranet/project/Shared Documents/document.aspx"
ClientContext: "var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("/sites/intranet/project/")